# Is leather and/or hide proficiency sufficient to wear studded leather?

Tags: dnd-4e

In D&D 4e, is a proficiency in leather and/or hide sufficient to wear studded leather? Or are these distinct base armor types? I am finding conflicting sources of information.

For some background, a Bard Tiefling wants to wear studded armor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, it is not sufficient.

A character using Studded Leather armor would need the feat [Armor Proficiency: Studded Leather](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3600).  Without that feat the character would take a -2 on all to hit rolls as well as to Reflex.

A prerequisite of that feat is Armor Proficiency: Hide Armor.

Comment: Next time I have a question about whether a proficiency covers a certain type of weapon/armor, should I just look at the list of proficiency feats in the compendium and if one exists for that weapon/armor then assume it is needed? I want to make sure I don't need to bother rpg.SE again with a question like this.

Comment: @user2525 - you can check the compendium or the book that the item was released in.

Comment: Yes, the online compendium is great for running things like this down (You can see the pre-reqs and then easily search the pre-req feat's pre-reqs).  Another exampel would be Full Plate proficiency which has its own unique little bonus. If your players are of a high enough level there may be a masterwork armor that does almost the same thing as studded and wouldn't cost them a feat.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith - studded has the interesting "tough" (ignore the first crit) property.  It seems pretty sweet.

Comment: In the compendium, the item "studded leather" is listed as "Type: Leather" without mention of prerequisites. How come?

Comment: If you just look up the item in the compendium then yes, but if you look up studded leather under feats you will find Armor Proficiency: Studded Leather which requires you to be proficient with Hide armor as a pre-req. The same exact thing happens if you look up full plate under items. It describes it (math and fluff) but has not mention of pre-reqs, but if you wouldn't be able to equip it legally and the character builder wouldn't even let you until you had the feat for it (whereas it shows the pre-reqs in feats). The feats and glossary sections of the compendium tend to be more complete.